# nested expect() function with Jasmine BDD does not evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I have the following Jasmine context and assertion:

```
it "should return a javascript file", ->
  # We make a request to /x.js
  request {uri: 'http://localhost:3000/x.js'}, (err, res, body) ->
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual 200
```

When I call Jasmine to evaluate the spec, it does not pickup the assertion. How can I make it pickup the assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `it()` is exiting before your request returns a response.  With jasmine, you have to think about asynchronous events a bit harder.

Check out [`waitsFor()`](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs) and do something like this, which will prevent your spec from exiting until the callback is executed, or the default timeout period has elapsed.

```
it "should return a javascript file", ->
  responded = no
  request {uri: 'http://localhost:3000/x.js'}, (err, res, body) ->
    responded = yes
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual 200

  waitsFor -> responded
```

This will also cause your spec to fail if the server times out, because each `waitsFor()` expects to be satisfied eventually.